# Starting IOS app from other developer asks for key

Tags: ios

```
//Set the config    
self.variables = (configuration?.objectForKey(config_key))! as! NSDictionary
```

I just started developing for IOS and have a mobile app which I downloaded from a shared bitbucket.

I just ran the app to make sure that it works and it spit back this error. It sounds like there is some key that is missing. I am no longer in contact with the developer for this app. Does this app require some sort of key or is this just a bug that I can work through?

(And if it is just a bug, a fix or suggestion on where to go would be great)

**EDIT 1**

It also spit out this error:

2016-04-21 03:26:15.962 APP_NAME[####:######] [Crashlytics] Version 3.3.4 (82)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

**EDIT 2**

These are the lines of code before the line that causes the error

```
    //Obtain the configuration to be used
let config_key: String = bundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey("Configuration") as! String

    //Obtain Path to config file
let config_file_path : String? = bundle.pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
let configuration = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: config_file_path!);
```

**EDIT 3**

Opening config.plist reveals a list api endpoints that are rather old. I believe that this may be causing the issue, but these are not keys, so I am definitly unsure about this

Comment: It seems that in this `Config.plist` file there are all the libraries's keys. Try to generate your own keys and to put them there

Comment: @LucaD I will look into that  thanks

Comment: Check your key for Crashlytics or any other third party library which you are using in your app. It seems thats wrong or missing in Config.plist file

Comment: If you are using Crashlytics, Check key for Fabric in your Config.plist file

Comment: @NileshMahajan If i have not downloaded or bought crashlytics is that an  issue?

Comment: Check Fabric and Crashlytics library in your Frameworks. It might be added there. If that's  an issue it should show some linker error.  Check only key which you are using for it or any other third party library.

Comment: hmm. Just looking at the code you have pasted makes me wonder if this app is a good choice. I can see a number of possible issues with it and the style is inconsistent. I would suggest a better idea might be to look into a progressive tutorial on iOS development where you learn one thing at a time rather than starting with a poorly written app. And that just aside from the fact that if this is a demo app for learning, it should work without issue and be a simple as possible. ie. nothing like crash analytics. Learn the basics first.

Comment: @drekka Yea, this app is for my company and there is a small bug that needs fixing and I drew the short straw. (we are really small and have no mobile devs)

Comment: Ahh ok. Well, then some patience will be needed :-) From the code you pasted you might find bugs around the usage of '!'. If something goes wrong  and the variable is a null then it will crash the app. It looks like the original author liberally used '!' without properly handling possible nulls. Getting your head around null handling will be one of the biggest hurdles, but also the most valuable. Also you can remove the ';' from the end of any lines that have them.